# Importing Third Party Models in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, nmos

I am trying to import the 2N3904 NMOS transistor in LTSpice but the program is not allowing me. I have pasted the model name in the spice schematic as shown below. The error message is : "cannot find 2n3904". Please let me know how I can fix this problem. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Have you read LTSpice documentation about this?

Comment: LTspice also has a built-in 2N3904 model.  You just need to select the correct base component first, as hinted at by Andy in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

> *I am trying to import the 2N3904 NMOS transistor in LTSpice but the
> program is not allowing me.*

Hint - the 2N3904 is not an NMOS transistor

Extra hint: -

[image]